# Writing point geometries with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geometry, cursor

Can someone help me fix some code that simply writes points into a featureclass?

It used to work in the older `gp.` syntax, but I'm having difficulties rewriting it in ArcPy for ArcGIS 10.0. In this example it was meant to create a 100m grid of points.

```
desc = arcpy.Describe("Grid_Extent")
Ext1 = str(desc.Extent)
Ext2 = Ext1.split(' ')
SXMin = int (float(Ext2[0]))
SXStart = int (float(Ext2[0]))
SYMin = int (float(Ext2[1])) 
SXMax = int (float(Ext2[2]))
SYMax = int (float(Ext2[3]))

XMin = SXMin
XMax = SXMax
YMin = SYMin
YMax = SYMax
print str(YMin) + "    " + str(YMax)
print str(XMin) + "    " + str(XMax)
while YMin < YMax:
  while XMin < XMax:
     cur = arcpy.InsertCursor("Grid_100")
     pnt = arcpy.Point()
     pnt.x = XMin
     pnt.y = YMin
     feat = cur.newRow()
     cur.insertRow(feat)
     XMin = XMin + 100
  XMin = SXStart
  YMin = YMin + 100
del cur
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are very close, just a few minor changes should make this work.  First when setting the point object x and y, the code should be:

```
pnt.X = XMin
pnt.Y = YMin
```

Then you need to set the geometry of the feature object from the point:

```
feat = cur.newRow()
feat.shape = pnt
cur.insertRow(feat)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that drove me crazy for hours. If I could ask another question inside of this question...   The point geometry does save into the featureclass now, however I had 2 items in that featureclass that are not getting populated.  (They weren't shown above to keep the question simple)    pnt.GRIDID = PNTNUM   pnt.GRIDLINE = LINENUM   any idea, or should I post this as a new question.   Thanks!

Comment: Should be setting the attributes on the feature, not the point object.  Try something like this: feat.GRIDID = PNTNUM and feat.GRIDLINE = LINENUM.  Do this before you insert the new row.

Comment: You beat me to it. feat.GRIDID and feat.GRIDLINE It works.  Thanks again!